# How to split table creation into commands

Tags: tables, macros

How to split table creation into separate commands or macros:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X|X}
    A & B
\end{tabularx}
```

Like this:

```
\newcommand{\tableHeader}{\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X|X}}
\newcommand{\tableRow}{A & B}
\newcommand{\tableFooter}{\end{tabularx}}

\tableHeader
\tableRow
\tableFooter
```

Comment: With `tabularx` you need an environment because it looks specifically for the `\end{tabularx}` (or `\end{somethingelse}`)

Comment: So it's not possible to do? Do I need to use it in one block?

Comment: At least the `\end{tabularx}` has to be visible.  If in your example I replace `\tableFooter` by `\end{tabularx}` it works.  The rest can be in macros

Comment: I see, thank you for clarification

Comment: If you are using LuaTeX, it is possible to replace `\end{tabularx}` with another command that you prefer.